# How can I get a selenium variable from selenium API which indicates selenium is still running

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, plugins

I want to make a Firefox plugin which indicates me on the browser that Selenium is still running and for that I am trying to understand, that how selenium interact with the Firefox or other browser because there must be some variables which statically resides during the execution by which I can get the status of selenium execution.

Answer (score 0):

Your question strikes me as putting the cart before the ox.  When you create a WebDriver instance and use the .get(url) method you create the browser instance.  When selenium stops running, that browser instance is destroyed.  So as long as you see that browser instance selenium is running.  Or am I failing to understand your question?

**Updated**

But to answer the question you could update a property file (Java) when a browser instance is created in a @Before hook and again when the browser instance is destroyed in the @After hook. Your plugin (in another browser?) could poll the property file.